# Fetch data using group by but last updated record

Tags: mysql

I want to display records on the basis of last updated , if updated column is empty then create date

| Id | SubjectId | MarksId | Entry date | Updated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-09-25 | 2022-11-25 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2022-12-25 | null |

It should print:-

| Id | SubjectId | MarksId | Entry date | Updated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-09-25 | 2022-11-25 |

If data is like below:-

| Id | SubjectId | MarksId | Entry date | Updated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-09-25 | null |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2022-12-25 | null |

It should print:-

| Id | SubjectId | MarksId | Entry date | Updated Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-12-25 | null |

I am writing below query but unable to fetch the same it everytime fetches the second thing even though I have updatedate present

```
     select Id,at.SubjectId,at.marksid 
from student at 
INNER JOIN (
      select MAX(Id) as StudentId from student  
       group by SubjectId,marksid
      ORDER BY COALESCE(UPDATEDATE,ENTRYDATE) desc 
      ) maxat ON at.Id=maxat.StudentId
```

Further info.

MySQL version 8.0

Entry date cant be null it will have data, Kind of auto generated when data inserts to this table

Comment: "unable to fetch the same" - what does that mean? What happens instead?

Comment: It fetches the second thing even though i have data like first use case

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Entry date cant be null  it will have data, Kind of auto generated when data inserts to this table

Comment: MYSQL-8 is the version

Comment: Keep in mind to add **all relevant information** to your question, not to the comment section

Comment: Okay sure next time will do

Answer (score 0):

Please include all the details in the question so it could help future readers as well.

As per the question using row_number is one option.

```
select Id,
       SubjectId,
       MarksId,
       Entrydate,
       UpdatedDate
from (  select *,
               row_number() over(partition by SubjectId,MarksId order by (case when UpdatedDate is null then Entrydate else Entrydate  end) desc) as rn
        from student
     ) tbl
where rn=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/di517ZLv